# How can I select the last index of a column split with bigquery

Tags: android, mysql, google-bigquery

There are a lot of questions about splitting a BigQuery, MySQL column, but I can't find one that fits my situation.

I am processing a large dataset (3rd party) that includes a freeform location field to normalize it for my Android app. When I run a `select` I'd like to split the column data by commas, take only the last segment and trim it of whitespace.

So far I've come up with the following by Googling documentation:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LOWER(SPLIT(location, ',')[OFFSET(-1)])) FROM `users` WHERE location <> ''
```

But the `-1` trick to split at last element does not work (with either offset or ordinal). I can't use `ARRAY_LENGTH` with the same array inline and I'm not exactly sure how to structure a nested query and know the last column index of the row.

I might be approaching this from the wrong angle, I work with Android and NoSQL now so I haven't used MySQL in a long time

**How do I structure this query correctly?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I'd like to split the column data by commas, take only the last segment ...

You can use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(location))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]
```

Below is an example illustrating it:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1,2,3,4,5' location UNION ALL
  SELECT '6,7,8'
)
SELECT location, ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(location))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] last_segment
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row location    last_segment     
1   1,2,3,4,5   5    
2   6,7,8       8
```

For trimming - you can use LTRIM(RTRIM()) - like  in

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(location))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]))
```

Comment: I'd like the segment, not just it's index. So I'll need to reverse it again? Is it expensive to reverse (twice)?

Comment: that's is exactly what my answer does - just try - and if still not as what you asked  - update your question with example of input and expected output

Comment: trying to read your question differently from how I did initially - are saying that you need output the whole original location field but with the last segment being trimmed?

Comment: No, this is my best-effort approach to get a rough approximation of country from freeform addresses. This solution works and is at least part of the problem solved - thanks

Comment: I noticed i have 181 records with no value despite my where clause. If there is no comma in this query, does it return nothing?

Comment: no. in case if there is no comma in the location field  - it will return the whole field as it is the only segment (thus last segment)

Comment: but consider options with location being NULL or location being just spaces (for example) so trimming will make it empty string

Answer (score -1):

To get the last part of the split string, I use the *len(string) - len(replace(string,delimeter,''))* trick to count the number of delimiters:

`split(<string>,'-')[OFFSET(length(<string>)-length(replace(<string>,'-',''))]`

Comment: This technically works but is quite painful to read because it means whatever logic used to build the array has to be duplicated.